# Charge on an electrical conductor

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, electric-fields, charge, conductors

Consider we have very sophisticated equipment (s) needed for this question. There's a finitely big uncharged conducting sphere. Suppose we had an extra electron from an external source and we plan to keep it on the sphere. Then how would that one electron arrange itself on the sphere? Where would it be placed?

> I'm aware of the fact that the net electric field inside a conductor is zero. Considering it to be very basic I don't need a proof for that. If there would be 2 or more electron it's very easy to think about how would they align themselves in order to cancel the net electric field at any point inside the conductor. But when there's only one electron it's hard to imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An uncharged conducting sphere contains many, many electrons, some bound and some unbound (free).

It is not the added electron which “rearranges” itself, rather it is the rest of the electrons which rearrange themselves to an equilibrium (minimum energy) state.

You seem to imply that adding two electrons is simpler by putting the electrons diametrically opposite to one another?
If this is done then there would still be a rearrangement of the rest of the electrons.

Comment: I got what tried to explain here, but can you just add something more to it so that it becomes clearer. Thanks

Comment: @GouravMahunta What is it that you need clarification on?

Comment: I mean on what exactly is going to happen when we add that 1 electron.

Comment: @GouravMahunta The charges within the conductor rearrange themselves.

Comment: But wherever an electron pops out from the surface, therez an positive cavity created. How will it affect the electric field then? I mean only the extra charge can affect the field.

Comment: The extra charge will affect all of the the  free electrons.